# IIS Crash on stack overflow (unhandled) - Microsoft .NET 4.5 ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, stack-overflow, w3wp

I have wrong behavior of ASP.NET MVC 3 application on IIS 7. We had stack overflow condition in code and it caused general application pool crash **without correct System.StackOveflowException throwing**. So, after starting of executing problematic function **w3wp.exe goes down with native code exception**.

Here is the code of HtmlHelper extension(now - fixed):

```
public static string Avatar( this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
    {
        return helper.UserAvatar(fileName);
    }

public static string UserAvatar( this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            return EmptyPhotoImage(helper);

        var photoPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(string.Format("~/Content/avatars/{0}", fileName));
        if (!File.Exists(photoPath))
            return EmptyPhotoImage(helper);

        return Avatar(helper, fileName);

    }
```

Here is the event log record:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17725, time stamp: 0x4ec4aa8e
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000055d7f
Faulting process id: 0x1a6c
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce6c67c7179807
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 0dd50093-d85b-11e2-9ee7-50e549e13906
```

Other one:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: w3wp.exe
P2: 7.5.7601.17514
P3: 4ce7afa2
P4: ntdll.dll
P5: 6.1.7601.17725
P6: 4ec4aa8e
P7: c00000fd
P8: 0000000000055d7f
P9: 
P10:
```

My question: Why it causes pool crash without StackOverflowException?

Answer (score 1):

Because you cause a recursive infinite invokation.

Avatar invokes UserAvatar which invokes Avatar if a certain condition is met, e.g when you have no file on disk.

Hence the StackOverflowException, which makes it impossible for the application to keep on running. Thats why you get a native exception (since it's the CLR that is crasching. Event 0xc00000fd is a StacokOverflowException)